# Multiplication Table line cross

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write("<table border='1' align='center' cellpadding='20'>");
    for (j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
        var n;
        document.write('<tr>');
        for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            if (i == j) {
                document.write('<td align="right" bgcolor="green">', i * j, '</td>');
            } else if (i * j == n + 1) {
                document.write('<td align="right" bgcolor="blue">', i * j, '</td>');
            }
            else {
                document.write('<td align="right">', i * j, '</td>');
            }
        }
        document.write("</tr>");
    }
    document.write("</table>");
</script>
```

My science computer class teacher asked the class to make Multiplication Table and to find out the equasion needed to make cross lines and to paint them.
After we do that he asked us to paint the triangles that will left in the multiplication table after the cross lines(in different colors each one).
I got the left to right cross line, if i==j, the other one i think i got too, if i*j==n+1.
But i dont know really how to add this n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what the question and normally I dont just deliver code, but is this it?

I took the liberty to rename your variable and hoist them. This way the code is more self-explaining after my opinion

```
var start = 1,
    end = 10,
    x, y;

document.write("<table border='1' align='center' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>");
for (x = start; x <= end; x++) {
    document.write('<tr>');
    for (y = start; y <= end; y++) {

      if (x === y) {
        document.write('<td>&nbsp;</td>');
      }
      else if (start+end - x == y) {
        document.write('<td>&nbsp;</td>');
      }
      else if ( start+end - x > y ) {
        if ( x < y )
          document.write('<td>1</td>');
        else
          document.write("<td>2</td>");
      }
      else {
        if ( x < y )
          document.write('<td>3</td>');
        else
          document.write("<td>4</td>");
      }

    }
    document.write("</tr>");
}
document.write("</table>");
```

http://jsbin.com/usesoz/5/edit

Comment: Yes! Thank you, I had another question.
With the triangles, you see some blank white cubes? They all make a triangle, i need to paint every one of the triangles in different color.

Comment: @user1885604 You are not a hard worker yourself?

Comment: @user1885604 Look here: http://jsbin.com/usesoz/3/edit

Comment: I am, its just the first time in class that i didnt understand something like this, I cant get it. I cant see it through my eyes I guess. I was trying to look for an answer for like 4 hrs now.

Comment: @user1885604 The key of knowledge is knowing to ask the right question.

Comment: @user1885604 btw. i hoped it helped :)